# issue related to multiple mat-table in *ngFor in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

i have following HTML

```
 <mat-accordion>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let panel of SummaryData">
          <mat-expansion-panel-header class="custom-mat-expansion-panel-header">
            <mat-panel-title>
              <div class="yelloWarnning"></div>
              <div>
                <p>{{panel.startTime}}</p>
                <p>{{panel.endTime}}</p>
              </div>
            </mat-panel-title>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="table-container" *ngFor='let type of panel.types'>
              <ng-template *ngFor="let tbl of type.Tables">
               <table mat-table  [dataSource]="tbl"  class="mat-elevation-z8">
                <ng-container  matColumnDef="BinningName">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Binn Name </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.BinningName}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container  matColumnDef="xAxis">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>xAxis </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.xAxis}} </td>
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container  matColumnDef="yAxis">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> yAxis </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.yAxis}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableColumns;"></tr>

              </table>
            </ng-template>
            </div>

          </div>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
```

i am getting following error :

```
Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource
```

i have some dynamic logic in component.ts which sets array in `types`
i have following code in typescript that generate object:

```
   self.startDateEndDateList.map(function (item) {

      let binnObjectsByType:any =[];
      binningType.map(function (binType) {
        let binningObjects = self.OriginData.binnings.filter(x => x.startTime == item.startTime && x.endTime == item.endTime && x.type == binType);
        let row:any ={'Type': binType};
        let tables:any=[];
        binningObjects.map(function(binObj){
            let iOriginData:any = {"vin":self.OriginData.vin,"binnings":[]};
            iOriginData.binnings.push(binObj);
            let BinningDataHandlerObject :BinningDataHandler = new BinningDataHandler(iOriginData,"BinningTable");
            tables.push({"BinningName":BinningDataHandlerObject.SelectedBinningName,"xAxis":BinningDataHandlerObject.xAxisFinalValue,"yAxis":BinningDataHandlerObject.yAxisFinalValue });
        });
        binnObjectsByType.push({'Type': binType,'Tables':tables});
      });

      self.SummaryData.push({"startTime":item.startTime,"endTime":item.endTime,"types":binnObjectsByType});
    });
```

is it possible to place mat-table in a for loop?

Thanks.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, `[dataSource]="tbl"` is not an array, observable nor data source. What is in the `type.Tables` items that is not any of the acceptable input types?

Comment: tbl is an array of json object as i have edited question you can see in component code.  binnObjectsByType.push({'Type': binType,'Tables':tables});

Comment: No it's not, `{"BinningName":BinningDataHandlerObject.SelectedBinningName,"xAxis":BinningDataHandlerObject.xAxisFinalValue,"yAxis":BinningDataHandlerObject.yAxisFinalValue }` is not an array, the `Tables` property is an array, but its items are objects and since you are iterating over `Tables` and serving each item to an `md-table` it won't be an array, it would be the object `{"BinningName" ...`

Comment: Quick way to prove it, replace the `<table md-table ... > ... </table>` with `{{ tbl | json }}` and then you'll see the item you're supplying to the `mdTable`.

Comment: then how should i add whole object in an array ?

Comment: Well, to start you can remove the `<ng-template *ngFor="let tbl of type.Tables">` and use `<table ... [dataSource]="type.Tables"` directly.